# How to sort gridview from client side without clicking on header

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a `grid-view` on my web page but without headers.
I need to sort `grid-view` from client side.Using any `button` or `drop-down` list which has column name in `data-text` field and column index in `data-value` field.
I found a tutorial on this site

[See Demo](http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/sortabletable/demo.html)

This works fine for table.But it not working for grid-view.
Can any one tell me how can i use this on grid-view.

Comment: You can try jquery datatable.

Comment: any example of jquery datatable with asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Following posts will give you some starting point about jQuery DataTables.

Building a complete ajax CRUD system with Asp.Net [1](http://naspinski.net/post/REAL-AJAX-with-AspNet-%28not-AspNet-AJAX%29.aspx)

ASP.NET and jQuery DataTables – The Basics [2](http://blueorbitsoftware.com/blog/?p=17)